# Every time I try accessing a post it redirects me to the feed

Tags: posts, redirect, urls, feed

I'm having some issues with my posts. Every time I try to acces one it leads me to the post feed. Even if I try manually writing the URL it leads me to the feed.

Comment: You mean the page redirects to the feed? (And by feed you mean archive page in WordPress terms, not the RSS feed?) Can you work out where the redirect is coming from: is it an HTTP redirect, or a JavaScript redirect? From your theme's template?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured out myself.

In case someone needs the solution:

You have to enter in Setings>Permalinks

[image: menu route]

Then in case you are using a custom structure select %postname% and it should work

[image: Custom structure configuration]

I think using Post name structure should solve the problem too